# R memory usage of each variable

Tags: r, variables, memory

Using R now, and my memory is almost full(gc() applied already). Is there a way to know each variables' memory consumption so that I know which one takes the most memory and remove that one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes there is, try:

```
object.size()
```

Comment: If you notice a large difference between the space required by your objects and their object size you can also try saving your working space via `save.image()` restarting R and loading your workspace.

Comment: you could e.g. have worked out the perfect method to get a sorted human-readable list, as the asker wanted “each variables’ memory consumption”: `sizes <- sapply(ls(), function(n) object.size(get(n)), simplify = FALSE); print(sapply(sizes[order(as.integer(sizes))], function(s) format(s, unit = 'auto')))`

Comment: Great comment. I've put these commands in a function and inverse the ordering: `list_obj_sizes <- function(list_obj=ls(envir=.GlobalEnv)){
 sizes <- sapply(list_obj, function(n) object.size(get(n)), simplify = FALSE)
 print(sapply(sizes[order(-as.integer(sizes))], function(s) format(s, unit = 'auto')))
}
`. It's easier to use: `list_obj_sizes()`

Comment: ok, I agree. Could've, SHOULD'VE. Thanks for the great additions!